# Get resource id from GetBackground

Tags: java, android, view, controls, drawable

I created a component having inherited it from View. Tell me please, how I can get resource id (int) from drawable (GetBackground function). Thanks.

Comment: That's generally not something you do, because a Drawable doesn't have to come from a resource.  Why are you trying to do that, there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy!

### Step 1:

When background resource is being set, save the id in an int.

```
int backgroundId;
onButton1Click(View v) {
backgroundId = R.drawable.myBackgroundResource;
((yourViewType)findViewById(R.id.myView)).setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
}
```

### Step 2:

Use your saved int.

```
onButton2Click(View v) {
// Your background id is known here.
someView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
// Or some other uses!
}
```

Comment: Actually, it doesnt solve the problem because the main purpose is to get the current background resource.

Comment: This does not provide the answer to the question IMHO. What about trying to fetch a background id from outside of the activity or fragment where it is set (e.g while writing a unit test)?